# Parse and evaluating a string locally?

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

For languages that allow for meta-programming is it possible to parse and evaluate a string locally? For example within a function? I'm trying to do this in Julia currently but also curious about the ability of other languages?

Comment: what does it mean " parse and evaluate a string locally"?

Comment: If you mean dynamically evaluate a string at runtime like Meta.parse and eval in julia do, most popular script language like Python, JavaScript and Ruby also provide eval function to dynamically evaluate string as expression at runtime. Actually LISP was the first language using eval back in 1958.

Comment: Doing this is rarely a good idea. Isn't there some other way to achieve what you want?

Comment: I believe we need to close this question unless @Thomas Leyshon provides some information what he exactly means. Perhaps an example in other language could help? `Meta.parse` and `eval` are also my candidates here ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
function foo()
    println("Calling foo")
end

function main(functionName)
    functionCall = @eval $(Symbol(functionName))
    functionCall()
end
```

Calling `main` with the function name `"foo"` string passed evaluates `foo`

```
julia> main("foo")
Calling foo
```

Comment: Thanks @Bebotron! Yes, so along those lines. But my issue is that if you parse and eval within a function the variable that has just been parsed is stored in the global workspace. That means if one repeatably calls that function the global workspace gets reaches its capacity and slows (if not crashes) the programme massively. For example :   `function bar()     eval(Meta.parse("c=4"))          c_squared = c^2     return c_squared end `. Calling `bar()` will produce a variable c in the global workspace

Comment: Sorry not sure how to make separate code blocks yet?

Comment: @DNF can you expand on that? When is it a good idea for example? Thanks!